# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a simple text based Dungeon game using Python3. First the user is prompted to select the hero from screen.py file.

```
from game import *


class GameScreen:
    '''Display the current state of a game in a text-based format.
    This class is fully implemented and needs no
    additional work from students.'''

    def initialize_game(self):
        '''(GameScreen) -> NoneType
        Initialize new game with new user-selected hero class
        and starting room files.'''

        hero = None
        while hero is None:
            c = input("Select hero type:\n(R)ogue (M)age (B)arbarian\n")
            c = c.lower()
            if c == 'r':
                hero = Rogue()
            elif c == 'm':
                hero = Mage()
            elif c == 'b':
                hero = Barbarian()

        self.game = Game("rooms/startroom", hero)

    def play(self):
        '''(Game) -> NoneType
        The main game loop.'''

        exit = False
        while not exit:
            print(self)
            if self.game.game_over():
                break
            c = input("Next: ")
            if c in ['q', 'x']:
                print("Thanks for playing!")
                exit = True
            elif c == 'w':  # UP
                self.game.move_hero(-1, 0)
            elif c == 's':  # DOWN
                self.game.move_hero(1, 0)
            elif c == 'a':  # LEFT
                self.game.move_hero(0, -1)
            elif c == 'd':  # RIGHT
                self.game.move_hero(0, 1)
            elif c == 'r':
                ## RESTART GAME
                self.initialize_game()
            else:
                pass

    def __str__(self):
        '''(GameScreen) -> NoneType
        Return a string representing the current room.
        Include the game's Hero string represetation and a
        status message from the last action taken.'''

        room = self.game.current_room
        s = ""

        if self.game.game_over():
            #render a GAME OVER screen with text mostly centered
            #in the space of the room in which the character died.

            #top row
            s += "X" * (2 + room.cols) + "\n"
            #empty rows above GAME OVER
            for i in list(range(floor((room.rows - 2) / 2))):
                s += "X" + " " * room.cols + "X\n"
            # GAME OVER rows
            s += ("X" + " " * floor((room.cols - 4) / 2) +
                "GAME" + " " * ceil((room.cols - 4) / 2) + "X\n")
            s += ("X" + " " * floor((room.cols - 4) / 2) +
                "OVER" + " " * ceil((room.cols - 4) / 2) + "X\n")
            #empty rows below GAME OVER
            for i in list(range(ceil((room.rows - 2) / 2))):
                s += "X" + " " * room.cols + "X\n"
            #bottom row
            s += "X" * (2 + room.cols) + "\n"
        else:
            for i in range(room.rows):
                for j in room.grid[i]:
                    if j is not None:
                        if j.visible:
                            s += j.symbol()
                        else:
                            #This is the symbol for 'not yet explored' : ?
                            s += "?"
                s += "\n"
        #hero representation
        s += str(self.game.hero)
        #last status message
        s += room.status
        return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gs = GameScreen()
    gs.initialize_game()
    gs.play()
```

Whenever I run this code, I get this error: TypeError: **init**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) which has to do with Rogue() or other hero classes. Here's the hero.py.

```
class Rogue(Tile):
    '''A class representing the hero venturing into the dungeon.
    Heroes have the following attributes: a name, a list of items,
    hit points, strength, gold, and a viewing radius. Heroes
    inherit the visible boolean from Tile.'''

    def __init__(self, rogue, bonuses=(0, 0, 0)):
        '''(Rogue, str, list) -> NoneType
        Create a new hero with name Rogue,
        an empty list of items and bonuses to
        hp, strength, gold and radius as specified
        in bonuses'''

        self.rogue = rogue
        self.items = []
        self.hp = 10 + bonuses[0]
        self.strength = 2 + bonuses[1]
        self.radius = 2 + bonuses[2]
        Tile.__init__(self, True)

    def symbol(self):
        '''(Rogue) -> str
        Return the map representation symbol of Hero: O.'''

        #return "\u263b"
        return "O"

    def __str__(self):
        '''(Item) -> str
        Return the Hero's name.'''

        return "{}\nHP:{:2d} STR:{:2d} RAD:{:2d}\n".format(
                    self.rogue, self.hp, self.strength, self.radius)

    def take(self, item):
        '''ADD SIGNATURE HERE
        Add item to hero's items
        and update their stats as a result.'''

        # IMPLEMENT TAKE METHOD HERE
        pass

    def fight(self, baddie):
        '''ADD SIGNATURE HERE -> str
        Fight baddie and return the outcome of the
        battle in string format.'''

        # Baddie strikes first
        # Until one opponent is dead
            # attacker deals damage equal to their strength
            # attacker and defender alternate
        if self.hp < 0:
            return "Killed by"
        return "Defeated"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Problem**

In `GameScreen.initialize_game()`, you set `hero=Rogue()`, but the `Rogue` constructor takes `rogue` as an argument. (Said another way, the `__init__` of `Rogue` requires that `rogue` be passed in.) You likely have this same issue when you set `hero=Mage` and `hero=Barbarian`.

**The Solution**

Luckily the fix is simple; you can just change `hero=Rogue()` to `hero=Rogue("MyRogueName")`. Maybe you could prompt the user for a name in `initialize_game`, and then use that name.

**Notes on "at least 2 arguments (1 given)"**

When you see errors like this, it means that you have called a function or a method without passing enough arguments to it. (`__init__` is just a special method that is called when an object is initialized.) So when debugging stuff like this in the future, look at where you call a function/method, and where you define it, and make sure that the two have the same number of parameters.

One thing that is sort of tricky about these kinds of errors, is the `self` that gets passed around.

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.foo = 'foo'
... 
>>> myObj = MyClass()
```

In that example, one might think, "Weird, I initialized `myObj`, so `MyClass.__init__` was called; why didn't I have to pass in something for `self`?" The answer is that `self` is effectively passed in whenever the "object.method()" notation is used. Hopefully that helps clear up the error and explains how to debug it in the future.

Comment: Getting this error now! TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given) when I pass hero=Rogue('hello')

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error in Mage and Barbarian too. Now, whenever I pass argument while calling Rogue('Hello') I get this error "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)"

Comment: oh Sorry I made a mistake. It works fine now. Thank you so much for the good explanation. I clearly understood the object oriented concept and the use of first parameter "self".

Comment: For curiosity, what was the mistake? I was trying hard to come up with a reason you'd get that error, haha. Also, glad it helped.

Comment: This code in "self.game = Game("rooms/startroom", hero)" expects argument hero in Game class which I forgot to mention in actual Game class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Class Rogue:
    ...
    def __init__(self, rogue, bonuses=(0, 0, 0)):
       ...
```

`__init__` of your `Rogue` class needs parameter `rogue`, but you are instantiating it as `hero = Rogue()` in `initialize_game`.

You need to pass some appropriate parameter to it like `hero = Rogue('somename')`

Comment: Getting this error now! TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given) when I pass hero=Rogue('hello')