# Error passing function to pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a Python 2.7 script that calculates pi using the Monte Carlo method. Then I am trying to create a plot of the values of pi on a semi-log graph using pyplot. Here is my code:

```
from numpy.random import rand, seed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Initialize the random number generator with seed value of 1
seed(1)

## Set the dimensions of the square and circle and the total number of cycles
sq_side = 1.0
radius = 1.0
cycles = 1000000
total_area = sq_side**2

## The main function
def main():
    # Initialize a few variables and the X,Y lists for the graph
    i = 0
    N = 0
    Y = []
    X = []
    while not N == cycles:
        # Generate random numbers and test if they are in the circle
        x,y = rand(2, 1)
        if x**2 + y**2 <= 1.0:
            i += 1
        # Calculate pi on each cycle
        quarter_circle_area = total_area * i / cycles
        calculated_pi = 4 * quarter_circle_area / radius**2
        # Add the value of pi and the current cycle number to the X,Y lists
        Y.append(calculated_pi)
        X.append(N)
        N += 1
    return X, Y

## Plot the values of pi on a logarithmic scale x-axis
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(0, 1e6)
ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)
ax.scatter(main())

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jonathan/PycharmProjects/MonteCarlo-3.4/pi_simple.py", line 45, in <module>
    ax.scatter(main())
TypeError: scatter() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I've looked at Matthew Adams' explanation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947599/typeerror-init-takes-at-least-2-arguments-1-given-error?newreg=631892a1f29847bda49546ebfa33ebb3), but can't seem to get my head around the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the tuple of lists created by `main` into *separate arguments* to `ax.scatter`, either before passing them:

```
x, y = main()
ax.scatter(x, y)
```

or using the "splat" unpack syntax:

```
ax.scatter(*main())
```

The other argument, taking you to three, is the implicit first `self` argument to instance methods.