# What is wrong with my class code [Python]?

Tags: python, class, typeerror

this is my first post here so if there is any mistake let me know.

This is my code here:

```
import math
class Square():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length


    def getL(self,length):
        self.length = length
        print(length)


    def getP(self,length):
        return length * 4

    def getA(self,length):
        return length * length

    def __add__(self,another_square):
        return Square(self.length + another_square.length)

s1 = Square()
s2 = Square()
print(s1.setL(5))
print(s1.getP(5))
print(s1.getA(5))
print(s2.getP(12))
print(s2.getA(15))
s3 = s1 + s2
print(s3.getA())
```

When I run it gives me a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\programming.py", line 21, in <module>
s1 = Square()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument:'length'
```

I want to know what is wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you create an object for a Python class `__init__` will be called for initializing. Hence you need to pass the arguments of the same. In your case u should pass the length.
`s1 = Square(length_value)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947599/typeerror-init-takes-at-least-2-arguments-1-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass argument to your constructor.

```
s1 = Square(1) # will call Square.__init__(self, 1)
s2 = Square(2) # will call Square.__init__(self, 2)
```

It's not a big problem.

### Update

I rewrite your class:

```
import math
class Square():
    def __init__(self, length):    #return an instance of this class with 'length' as the default length.
        self.length = length

    def setL(self,length):    #pass length to the instance and override the original length.
        self.length = length

    def getL(self):           #get the length of instance.
        return self.length

    def getP(self):           #get the perimeter of instance.
        return self.length * 4

    def getA(self):           #get the area of instance.
        return self.length ** 2

    def __add__(self,another_square):     #return a new instance of this class with 'self.length + another_square.length' as the default length.
        return Square(self.length + another_square.length)
```

I think you can realize what is your real question after reading my code. And there is a test for the code above.

```
s1 = Square(1)
s2 = Square(2)
print(s1.getP())
print(s1.getA())
print(s2.getP())
print(s2.getA())
s3 = s1 + s2
print(s3.getA())

output:
4
1
8
4
9
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run the code now, it gives an error saying that s3 requires another positional argument 'length' but shouldn't it add the values of s1 and s2 and print it?

Comment: @Assassin'sOrder what error? Please update your question.

Comment: @Assassin'sOrder I will update the answer to explain you what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your class init requires a length parameter, and you are trying to create s1 without giving it one

Answer (score 1):

You should use the constructor for passing the value .
Like this.

```
s1 = Square(100) 
s2 = Square(482)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide length because in **init**() required length parameter  :

```
s1 = Square(5)
s2 = Square(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing instances of `Square` without specifying a `length` argument.

```
s1 = Square()
s2 = Square()
```

Yet according to your definition

```
def __init__(self, length):
    self.length = length
```

`length` is a required positional argument. You either need to define a sensible default value for this argument, e.g.

```
def __init__(self, length=1):
    self.length = length
```

or explicitly provide it when you initialize the object (e.g. `s1 = Square(1)`)