# Python Error - Child class cannot access parent class value and shows init() error or attribute error

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parent

I want to access the parent class variable 'bal' from the child class and make changes to that.

I tried using the child class without the init() fucntion but it showed that deposit is not an attribute of AccountHolder which is the parent class.

```
class AccountHolder(object):
    total = 0
    def __init__(self, acc_no, name, age, bal):
        self.acc_no = acc_no
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.bal = bal
        AccountHolder.total = AccountHolder.total + 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "\nName: {}\nBalance: {:10.2f}\n".format(self.name,         self.bal) 

    def update(self, new_bal):
        print"Old balance:", self.bal
        self.bal = new_bal
        print"New balance:", self.bal

    def totalAccHolders():
        print"Total no of account holders=", AccountHolder.total
    totalAccHolders = staticmethod(totalAccHolders)

class savingah(AccountHolder):          

    def __init__(self, acc_no, name, age, bal, dep):
        super().__init__(acc_no, name, age, bal)
        self.dep=dep

    def deposit(AccountHolder, new_bal):
      print"Old balance:", AccountHolder.bal
      self.bal += dep
      print"New balance:", AccountHolder.bal


 class loanah(AccountHolder):

     def __init__(self, acc_no, name, age, bal, wdraw):
            super().__init__(acc_no, name, age, bal)
            self.wdraw=wdraw

    def withdraw(self, new_bal):
        print"Old balance:", self.bal
        self.bal -= wdraw
        print"New balance:", self.bal

listAcc = []
b = savingah()   

while(True):
    print("\nMENU")
    print"1. Create a new AccountHolder"
    print"2. Update AccountHolder balance"
    print"3. Saving update"
    print"4. Loan update"
    op = int(input("Enter option - "))
    if op==1:
        listAcc.append(AccountHolder(int(input("Enter AccNo: - ")),
          input("Enter Name: "),
          int(input("Enter age: ")),
          float(input("Enter balance: "))))
        print(listAcc[-1])
        AccountHolder.totalAccHolders()
    elif op==2:
        s = input("Enter Account number - ")
        for a in listAcc:
            if s == a.acc_no:
                bal = float(input("Enter new balance - "))
                a.update(bal)
    elif op==3:
        s = input("Enter Account number - ")
        for a in listAcc:
            if s == a.acc_no:
                bal = float(input("Enter amount to be deposited - "))
                b.deposit(bal)
    elif op==4:
         s = input("Enter Account number - ")
         for a in listAcc:
            if s == a.acc_no:
                bal = float(input("Enter amount to be withdrawn - "))
                a.withdraw(bal)
    else:
        print "Invalid input\n"
        break
```

Error that I am getting with this code and if I remove the init function from savingah I get an error saying class AccountHolder init attribute isn't present -

```
[student@PC-16 ~]$ python vexp6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vexp6.py", line 33, in <module>
    b = savingah()       
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you just need to read your error! "**takes exactly 6 arguments**" just **1 given**. When calling `b = savingah()`, you need to give 5 more parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947599/typeerror-init-takes-at-least-2-arguments-1-given-error)